# Copy/paste Ashkenaz siddur with meteg

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book

Is there a copy/paste enabled siddur with full vocalisation and metegim?

None of the ones I know of (namely the Da'at.ac.il siddur) has either (in the named case, they often leave out cholamim).

Comment: if you finally find a siddur with metagim, you can answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62596/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think Adám's that answer there is the best one for that question.

Comment: Why? I've never seen that Siddur so it might not have what they are looking for

Comment: @DoubleAA, it doesn't work for mine, as Simanim isn't copy/paste, however, it fulfils all of the requirements of the OP there (source: my schul's sefer aftartah is a Simanim, as is my father's preferred tikkun)

Comment: I don't know how you know what their siddur looks like by looking at their tikkun

Comment: You might want to try the Davka Hebrew word processor. According to their website, "DavkaWriter 7 integrates the vowelized text of the Tanach, Rashi on Chumash, the Mishnah, and the Siddur for easy and convenient access."

Comment: @HaLailahHaZeh, In my experience, Davka is the most atrocious software available for Hebrew. I wouldn't get a licence for the whole package just for a vocalised text (which might not even get metagim)

Comment: Are you thinking of making your own digital printed nusach Ashkenaz siddur? I've thought of making my own in the style of a Koren after failing to find a good one but need to find some suitable base text too...

Comment: @Jakub, I've been working on one for awhile. It's annoying to have to do so much of the typing myself. I have experience with setting type though, so that bit is fairly easy.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Well, if you want to collaborate on a joint project I'd love to help out. I've had some experience with design, layout, and digital self publishing including some Jewish projects for the family (like bentchers, brachos sheets for teaching my children, and so on). I've found trying to lay out translated or transliterated text extremely frustrating but a siddur in Hebrew with English instructions (which is the format I mostly daven from at the moment, in a Koren edition) would be much simpler.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt But, yes, getting the copy (other than text from Torah) is the hardest part, especially correctly vocalised.

Comment: @Jakub, Here's the Facebook page for the siddur I'm working on. It should be possible to contact me through that. https://www.facebook.com/NachalasAharon/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel